# NTLM authentication using httplistener

Tags: c#, ntlm, httplistener

I want to implement NTLM authentication in httplistener written in C#. I could not find a good place on Internet to get this info. I have written Basic authentication, but cannot move forward using NTLM authentication.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the [`AuthenticationSchemes`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httplistener.authenticationschemes.aspx) property on your listener to `Negotiate`:

```
listener.AuthenticationSchemes = AuthenticationSchemes.Negotiate;
```

Comment: Hi @Darin. Do you think I can get a sample source code to authenticate using NTLM Authentication in C#? or if you can point to a site that will be helpful. thanks in advance.

Comment: I implemented using AuthenticationSchemes.Ntlm. I had issue earlier with this scheme, but resolved it using other means. thanks anyways.